# Accessing parent class variables

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I feel like this should be easy but I still can't get the darn thing to work properly.

I don't know what is best practice here. I first started out by trying to store the variable passed to the child class as by reference and then calling on it within the child class. Except, when the variable changes inside the parent class, the child is not seeing the change.

The child:

```
class Child
{
public:
    Child(bool &EndLoop);
    ~Child();

private:
    bool EndLoopRef;
};

Child::Child (bool &EndLoop) : EndLoopRef(EndLoop)
{
}

Child::PrimaryFunction()
{
    while (!Child::EndLoopRef)
    {
        // Main app function is in here
    }

    // EndLoop is true, we can now leave this method
}
```

The parent:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent();

private:
   bool EndLoop;
};

Parent::Parent()
{
    Child childclass(EndLoop);
    childclass.PrimaryFunction();

    // EndLoop was changed and the loop is now overe
}
```

To summarize this, parent class passes `EndLoop` by reference. The child class stores this reference and waits for a true value of EndLoopRef to exit the loop. Needless to say, it's not ending the loop.

FYI, the EndLoop value is changed by a system call in the parent class.

Comment: Private parts can only be accessed by the direct class; not by relatives.  You have *protected* variables in a base class which children can access.  Think first, if you really want children meddling with your parts.

Comment: Also, parents can't mess with child parts because parent's don't know how many children there will be nor their names (or parts) at compile time.

Comment: The EndLoopRef variable in the Child class is not a reference.  If you make it a reference.  You may have to be careful as the class Child does not control the scope of the variable and you may run into issues if the controlling class goes out of scope before the Child class is done using it.

Comment: Your `:: EndLoop(EndLoopRef)` cannot possibly compile. It's easier and less error-prone to test your code in a compiler before posting than it is to think about whether the code would compile.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Haha. That analogy. I moved it into a protected member and it still is not referencing the variable correctly. Even if it's passed by reference, the child can't see the variable if it's a private member?

Comment: @hvd Thank you. Fixed that.

Comment: According to the code posted, there is no inheritance.  Remember, you have a choice of `public`, `protected`, or `private` inheritance.  Something like `class Child: public Parent`.

Comment: You can give a reference to a private member (bind a reference to it - in your case you aren't doing it because Child::EndLoopRef is not a reference). Either way this is not a good way to use inheritance

Comment: There is no inheritance in your code and you do not need it. Your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming your class member `bool EndLoopRef;` does not make it a reference. This is still just a `bool` value, and the constructor's member initialisation will load `EndLoop`'s value at construction time.

You've already shown you know how to use `&` to define a reference.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I defined it as a regular value. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined it a a reference.
You have to say:

```
bool &EndLoopRef;
```

Answer (score -3):

A private variable should not be passed by reference. The best way to interact with  a private is to have a get() and set() method in the class which has the member variable. In this case your parent value could provide a getEndLoop() function that would return the boolean value.

```
    Child::PrimaryFunction()
{
    while (!Parent.getEndLoop())
    {
        // Main app function is in here
    }

    // EndLoop is true, we can now leave this method
}
```

Comment: Why is that? There is nothing wrong with passing private variables by reference.